# Counting JSON nodes in AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Alright, I have the following JSON code:

```
{
"productDetails": {
    "productThumb": "/uploads/testAdmin@dixoncom.com/showup-bg4.jpg",
    "productName": "Hamburger",
    "productDesc": "Made with 100% American ground beef",
    "productPrice": "9.99",
    "productModifiers": [{
        "Sides": [{
            "modifierName": "Applesauce",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "off"
        },{
            "modifierName": "Rice",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "off"
        }],
        "Toppings": [{
            "modifierName": "Bacon",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0.25",
            "isDefault": "off"
        }, {
            "modifierName": "Tomato",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "on"
        }],
        "Doneness": [{
            "modifierName": "Extra Well",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "off"
        },{
            "modifierName": "Well",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "off"
        }],
        "Breads": [{
            "modifierName": "White Bun",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "on"
        }, {
            "modifierName": "Whole Wheat Bun",
            "modifierUpcharge": "0",
            "isDefault": "off"
        }]
    }]
}
}
```

I ran it through jsonlint.com and verified that it comes back as valid JSON. In my jQuery, I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getItemDetails/"+productType+"/"+productID,
    type: "get",
    data: ({productType:productType, productID:productID}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var numMods = data.productDetails.productModifiers.length;
        console.log("There are "+numMods+" categories of modifiers.");
    }
});
```

For some reason however, my console.log returns as undefined. Basically, I need to know how many "categories" are inside the productModifiers node. So in this case, it should return 4 (Sides, Toppings, Doneness, and Breads). I can't seem to figure out what I am missing that will allow me to figure out how many child nodes are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, productModifiers is an array with one object in it that contains multiple keys for the categories you need. Therefore below is the code you'll need. If productModifiers can have more then 1 object, you'll need to loop over the objects to count your categories.

```js
var json = {
  "productDetails": {
    "productThumb": "/uploads/testAdmin@dixoncom.com/showup-bg4.jpg",
    "productName": "Hamburger",
    "productDesc": "Made with 100% American ground beef",
    "productPrice": "9.99",
    "productModifiers": [{
      "Sides": [{
        "modifierName": "Applesauce",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Rice",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }],
      "Toppings": [{
        "modifierName": "Bacon",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0.25",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Tomato",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "on"
      }],
      "Doneness": [{
        "modifierName": "Extra Well",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Well",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }],
      "Breads": [{
        "modifierName": "White Bun",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "on"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Whole Wheat Bun",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }]
    }]
  }
}


var numMods = Object.keys(json.productDetails.productModifiers[0]).length;
console.log("There are " + numMods + " categories of modifiers.");
```

Comment: This works great in getting the number of nodes. With that being said - how could I access the actual node names? (ie: Sides, Toppings, Doneness, Breads).

Comment: @JohnHubler `Object.keys(json.productDetails.productModifiers[0])` will contain the node names. Just save that to a variable before getting its length :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess even if your `productModifiers` holds an array; that array just holds single object with 4 keys. Could you please try with below code:

```js
var data = {
  "productDetails": {
    "productThumb": "/uploads/testAdmin@dixoncom.com/showup-bg4.jpg",
    "productName": "Hamburger",
    "productDesc": "Made with 100% American ground beef",
    "productPrice": "9.99",
    "productModifiers": [{
      "Sides": [{
        "modifierName": "Applesauce",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Rice",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }],
      "Toppings": [{
        "modifierName": "Bacon",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0.25",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Tomato",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "on"
      }],
      "Doneness": [{
        "modifierName": "Extra Well",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Well",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }],
      "Breads": [{
        "modifierName": "White Bun",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "on"
      }, {
        "modifierName": "Whole Wheat Bun",
        "modifierUpcharge": "0",
        "isDefault": "off"
      }]
    }]
  }
};

var productModifiersObj = data.productDetails.productModifiers[0];

var count = 0;
var i;

for (i in productModifiersObj) {

  if (productModifiersObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    count++;
  }
}

alert("There are " + count + " categories of modifiers.");
```

Comment: Rather then looping. See my answer, it's much easier and more efficient to just get the Object.keys then get the length of the returned list. :)

Comment: `Object.keys` works on most modern browser though its not compatible with older IE browser...So its always better to go with universal compatible code.

Comment: Good to know and quite true.